# Error trying to use namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use `JObject`, but I can't declare the namespace: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

I write this line at the top of my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject;
```

but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Read the error. That isn't a namespace.

Comment: You can legally use this syntax, but only if you want to redefine class name: `using JObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject; JObj j = new JObj;`

Answer (score 2):

Don't declare the type, just the namespace.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

JObject j = new JObject();
```

Alternatively, you can fully qualify the name every place you use it, if you don't want to use the using statement.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject j = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
```